# Swift parse check user entered input and refresh value

Tags: ios, swift, input, parse-platform, refresh

I am trying to check if user entered data matches object data in a class. Comparing works, but refreshing does not.

This is the code.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "registeredCodes")
    query.whereKey("code", equalTo: userCodeEnter.text!)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil || object == nil {
            print("The getFirstObject request failed.")
        } else {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved the object.")
            let totalPoints = PFUser.currentUser()?["points"] as? Int
            self.userPointsLabel.text =  "Punkte: " + "\(totalPoints)"


        }
            }
```

After

```
let totalPoints = PFUser.currentUser()?["points"] as? Int
            self.userPointsLabel.text =  "Punkte: " + "\(totalPoints)"
```

It just puts an "optional" in front of the original number, but not the new one. It looks something like `optional(5)`

Comment: so a number isn't being updated? where do you update it?

Comment: @Wain for now manually in parse.

Comment: Do you pull the user update somewhere ? Your code shows you pull a different kind of object, not the current user.

Comment: @Wain After the print("Successfully retrieved the object.") I am trying to, doesn't work so I was asking what I did wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is querying (pulling an object from the server, with some check) for the `registeredCodes` class. Then, when that's done, your code is using the `PFUser.currentUser` to do something. This is a different class. The query will not result in an update to the `PFUser.currentUser`.

If `PFUser.currentUser` is expected to have changed then you need to call `refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:` on it to get those updates so you can use them (they will be ready when the completion block is called.